# Phonons are bosons, but still we apply Maxwell distribution in einstein model. Why?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, maxwell-equations, bose-einstein-condensate

Phonons are bosons, but still we apply Maxwell distribution in the no.of oscillator while calculating the total energy and specific heat from it in the Einstein model, can anyone explain why?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

In quantum mechanics, concentration depends on temperature. Therefore, at high temperature, most systems will obey the Maxwell limit (classical limit).

Actually, both Bose–Einstein and Fermi–Dirac become Maxwell–Boltzmann statistics at high temperature or low density.